# javascript hoisting and execution context

Tags: javascript

```
var employeeId = 'abc123';

function foo() {
    employeeId = '123bcd';
    return;

    var employeeId = function(){}
}
foo();
console.log(employeeId);
```

I am new to javascript programming, could someone explain to me why above 
output is 'abc123' not '123bcd', I thought the employeeId defined inside 
foo() should be global variable and overwrite the outside one, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
var employeeId = function(){}
```

JavaScript actually hoists `employeeId` and the code becomes this:

```
function foo() {
    var employeeId;
    employeeId = '123bcd';
    return;

    employeeId = function(){}
}
```

Since `var`s declared inside a function have the scope same as of function block, it doesn't overwrite the outer `employeeId`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if I change 'var employeeId = function(){}' to 'function employeeId(){}', is the result going to be same?

Comment: @chen.w -- I recommend you to try it first and observe the behaviour on your own. If you still don't understand, I will be glad to help.

Comment: Yeah I just try it on my own it turns out it behaved exact same as function expression, the output is still 'abc123', thank for your help!